# AWS Certificates Not Secure In Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, alias, amazon-elb

I created an X.509 certificate using the AWS certificate manager.

I used a wildcard designation, `*.mydomain.com`, and validated it using the AWS DNS.

I then attached it to my *Elastic Load Balancer (ELB)* along with the instances running my web service.

I then set up a *CNAME* record in my *AWS DNS* where the alias name is `dev.360yield.admin.mydomain.com` and points to the canonical *DNS* name of the *ELB*.

> I get the **"Not secure"** notice in the address bar when I use the
>   alias name in the address bar.

The error is the same as if I was using self-signed certificates. I thought that if I used *AWS* created certificates I would not get this error.

Are my assumptions incorrect?
Did I do something wrong with the setup of the certificate?

Comment: Take a look at [this question and the accepted answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/what-certificates-are-needed-for-multi-level-subdomains).  The short answer is that, because you have multi-level subdomains (i.e. `partA.partB.partC.example.com`) you'll need a certificate for each "level".

Comment: Reading what stunbar suggested shows that the only way it would work is to create a wildcard for each subdomain level or, \*.\*.\*.mydomain.com -- you have to have a " * " for each subdomain level.  Some of the RFC discussion suggested that some of the older browsers did not support this or interpreted it slightly differently than described in the RFC.  Instead of getting into the browser test business, I just opted to create a dev.360yield.admin.mybrowser.com certificate and 
 www.dev.360yield.admin.mybrowser.com.  Once I did this, the browser successfully accepted the certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @stdunbar mentioned, this is not by AWS but how SSL wildcards work. For example, in this case dev-360yield-admin.mydomain.com should work, but for dev.360yield.admin.mydomain.com you would need a cert for *.360yield.admin.mydomain.com